# MongoDB Aggregation pipeline automatically decodes binary

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, pipeline, aggregation

In my schema, I have stored an image in binary format: `img: { type: Buffer }`.

When I'm using the .find() method, I receive the image, as expected, in binary form. If I try to get random data using the $sample pipeline, the binary data gets converted to a base64 string. I'm calling the aggregate method as follows:

```
Model.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: sampleSize } }])
```

Can someone please explain why this is happening?